# Finder always shows hidden files on startup

Tags: macos, finder

Starting a few weeks ago, I have been noticing a strange behaviour of Finder: Every time I launch it (that is, when I restart my Mac or after `killall Finder`), it shows me hidden files by default. I then need to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to turn it off. Not a great deal, but still annoying.

I've tried setting `defaults com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles` to `false`, `NO`, and `0`, yet this didn't help. Internet search did not yield any results either. Has anyone experienced similar behaviour and know how to fix it?

**UPDATE (for clarity):** I have (since recently) macOS 12.4 Monterey installed, yet the problem first appeared on 10.15.7 Catalina and stayed since then.

Comment: Delete preference list, Reset NVRAM.